# Webpack 5 and null-loader-esque functionality

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

Webpack 5 deprecated `null-loader`, which was helpful for excluding certain imports from client-side bundles. Now, the docs say that I should use the `resolve.alias` option with `false` instead, however, this thing doesn't accept regex keys like `null-loader` did. But I want to deliberately exclude specific imports matching a regex. I've tried `IgnorePlugin`, but that simply prevents the module from being added to the bundle but keeps the import, which breaks in the browser.

What's the intended solution here? Should I write my own loader to do what null-loader used to do?

Answer (score 2):

The deprecation note suggests that you can use regex. See `xyz$`: https://webpack.js.org/blog/2020-10-10-webpack-5-release/#deprecated-loaders

Try wrapping the regex key in single quotes if necessary. This seems to have worked for me.